# Mongoose.findOne doesn't return anything, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, mongoose, return

I need to return the search results from     `Mongoose.findOne`     to variable

```
results = Lang.findOne({page: params.page,lang: params.lang, param: params.param}, function(err, lang) {
  if( err || !lang) {
    console.log("No translation!");
  } else {           
    return lang.trans;
  };
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried several hours to find a solution with async. functions and nothing ...
I also found articles where it was said that this is impossible, but is there any alternative for realize this?

It's really important to me because I need this to my multilingual project, I need to get the translation:

```
 res.render('index',{titleGen : req.__({page:'home', lang:req.locale, param:'hello'})});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
exports.getLang = getLang = function(params,callback){

    console.log('received: '+params.page+' + '+params.lang+' + '+params.param);
    Lang.findOne({page: params.page, lang: params.lang, param: params.param},function(err, lang){
        if(err)
            console.log(err)
        else{
            callback(lang.trans);
        }
    });
}
```

and routing:

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.__({page:'home', lang:req.locale, param:'hello'},function(text){
        res.render('index',{titleGen : text });
    })
});
```